# Given an array of integers, find two numbers such that they add up to a specific target number

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I'm trying to solve problem of finding two numbers from an array such that they add up to a specific target number.
The simplest way to solve it (it gives TimeLimit Error, because it takes O(n^2) time)

```
vector<int> res, temp = numbers;
sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.size(); j++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target)
        {
            res.push_back(i + 1);
            res.push_back(j + 1);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Also I've tried to sort array before find and then use two pointers (Now it takes O(n^2 log n) time but still gives me Time Limit Error)

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> &numbers, int target) {
    vector<int> res, temp = numbers;
    sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    int i = 0, j = numbers.size() - 1;
    while (i < j)
    {
        if (temp[i] + temp[j] == target)
        {
            res.push_back(i);
            res.push_back(j);
            break;
        }
        if (temp[i] + temp[j] < target)
            i++;
        if (temp[i] + temp[j] > target)
            j--;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == temp[res[0]])
        {
            res[0] = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == temp[res[1]])
        {
            res[1] = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

So I would like to know how it is possible to solve this problem using only O(n) time?
I've heard somthing about hash and map but don't know what are they and how to use them.

Comment: Do not put ` around code blocks. Enter twice and indent by four spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash table approach is as follows: (using `unordered_set` in C++11)

- Given a target sum `S`...
- For each element `x`:

  - Check if `S - x` exists in the hash table - if so, we have our 2 numbers `x` and `S - x`.
  - Insert `x` into the hash table.

This runs in expected `O(n)` time.

---

Also, your approach is only `O(n log n)`. That's `O(n log n)` for the sort and `O(n)` for each of the while loop and the two for loops, giving `O(n log n + n) = O(n log n)` in total. Well, that's assuming `.size()` is `O(1)` - I know it might be `O(n)` (giving `O(n²)` total running time), at least for older compilers.

Although I'm not too sure what the last two for loops are doing there - when you break from the while loop, you'll have your 2 numbers.

Comment: Thank's a lot for quick answer.

Comment: Can you also say me where I can read simple and powerful things about hash tables with examples?

Comment: Yeah, you're right about O(n log n).

Comment: @York's Sorry, I don't really know of such a resource ... except maybe [so].

Comment: Dukeling, thank you, I'll try to find something.